# VBA Code for Powerpoint, changes all MS Object (from Excel) of all slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a lot of slides in Powerpoint. All have MS Object Connections to Excel tables. I am looking for a code, to changes the size and position of all this objects. I have some code already. But the problem is its also changes the size and position of texts. Do someone know how to changes it?

```
Sub ResizeAll()
For Each tSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
tSlide.Select
With tSlide.Shapes.Item(1)
'assume a blank slide with one image added only
   .Select
   .Height = 72 * 1000.39
   .Width = 72 * 10.67
'algin middle (Horizontal Center)
   .Left = 100
   .Top = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 5
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stay away from using the Selection object. This code checks that the shape is an OLE object, then resizes only that shape. If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify "also changes the size and position of texts".

```
Sub EnlargeExcelTables()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
        With oShape
          'Insert Size process here.
        End With
      End If
    Next oShape
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: I use tables in this PowerPoint file, this tables come from Excel as MS Object Connections. I want that all of this table, in all slides, have the same position and weidht and heigt.

Comment: But how can i deactive the lock aspect ratio?